# How to print or debug a value in json file

Tags: javascript, json

How to use a debugger like `console.log()` to write in JSON file and debug values.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), because the question doesn't have enough information to diagnose the problem. Please edit your post accordingly so that we can help you. Please see [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just save the `console.log` output to a file?

> Right click > Save as in the Console.

Otherwise there's the `console.save` JavaScript that may help you if I'm understanding your question properly.

http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save

```
(function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
})(console)
```

**Usage:**

`console.save(data, [filename])`

Comment: I am not asking that..in a  json file can i write console.log() ?? if  we cannot write,what can be written in place of that?

Comment: @mohanbabu I'm so confused with why you would want that in your JSON file?